# Java Mail with To, CC and BCC

Tags: java, email, bcc, carbon-copy

I am trying to send mail with to, cc and bcc. I am using javax.mail for achieving this. Please find below a part of my code

```
InternetAddress[] myToList = InternetAddress.parse("gopi.mani@xyz.com,Maimsa.SF@xyz.com");
InternetAddress[] myBccList = InternetAddress.parse("Usha.B@xyz.com");
InternetAddress[] myCcList = InternetAddress.parse("NEHA.SIVA@xyz.com");
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(objEmail.getFrom()));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,myToList);
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC,myBccList);
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,myCcList);
```

But when I try to execute this code, I am getting the below exception:

> javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
>   nested exception is:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 452 4.5.3 Too many recipients

Comment: Have you set the properties ?

Comment: "452 4.5.3 Too many recipients" leads me to believe a SMTP server is rejecting your email instead of a Java issue. Have you tried with just a single recipient to see if you continue to get this error?

Comment: Yeah i have set the properties like below,
Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", host_name);
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

Comment: Hi Steven,
If i use "message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,myToList);" alone and remove "BCC" and "CC" lines of code. My code is working fine. Please confirm if this is still a Java issue or the issue is with the SMTP server

Comment: @user2928305: That error message comes directly from the SMTP server.

Comment: @SLaks : Then my SMTP setting needs to be changed for me to send mails with CC and BCC right.

Comment: thanks steven and SLaks.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
InternetAddress[] myToList = InternetAddress.parse("gopi.mani@xyz.com,Maimsa.SF@xyz.com");
InternetAddress[] myBccList = InternetAddress.parse("Usha.B@xyz.com");
InternetAddress[] myCcList = InternetAddress.parse("NEHA.SIVA@xyz.com");
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(objEmail.getFrom()));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,myToList);
// changes,...
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC,myBccList);
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,myCcList);
```

Comment: addRecipient method allows only "Message" and Address as its parameters and not Address[] (array). only addRecipients allows arrays. I tried both the methods and still its failing.

Comment: Yes even then the exception is persisting.

Comment: your code seems to be correct and problem may be with SMTP server.It works for me with the code you posted

Answer (score 1):

```
InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of toaddresses
        for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }

        InternetAddress[] ccAddress = new InternetAddress[cc.length];

        // To get the array of ccaddresses
        for( int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++ ) {
            ccAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(cc[i]);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddress[i]);
        }

        InternetAddress[] bccAddress = new InternetAddress[bcc.length];

        // To get the array of bccaddresses
        for( int i = 0; i < bcc.length; i++ ) {
            bccAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(bcc[i]);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddress[i]);
        }
```

The not us .setRecipients if you need use CC or BCC